# Apostrophe in the title of feed generates error

Tags: php, special-characters, feed

When I try to generate the feed and these contain the title `'` in the browser which is interpreted as `’` browsers generate an error right at the character `’`, MySql contains the `'` and not `’` i try to replace with php but not work.

```
$domanda = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' and post_type = 'post' AND DATE(post_modified) > DATE(post_date) ORDER BY post_modified DESC LIMIT 50");
    $numrss = mysqli_num_rows($domanda);
    while ($info = $domanda->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
    $primodato=$info['post_title'];
    echo "<item>
    <title><![CDATA[".str_replace("'"," ",$primodato)."]]></title>";
```

[Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFAgQ.png)

[MySql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5Klh.png)

any solution?

header is set correct (i think)

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: Make your question simple. It's complicated..

Comment: Try `<title><![CDATA[".htmlentities($primodato,ENT_QUOTES,"iso-8859-1")."]]></title>";`

Comment: I have tryed not work =(

Comment: @user1038606 I have updated with `ENT_QUOTES`

Comment: thanks but nothing =(

Comment: Have you tried `utf8_encode($primodato)`?

Comment: yes, this work! THANKS!